# ColdFusion : URLDecode("%ara%") is giving me as %ar%

Tags: coldfusion

In ColdFusion, `URLDecode()` decodes the URL-encoded string (URL encoding formats some characters with a percent sign and the two-character hexadecimal representation of the character).

Example: `%3A` is the hex equivalent for ":(colon)"    When the `URLDecode()` is applied on different strings as below,

1. `URLDecode("%3A%")` = `:%` -- Valid
2. `URLDecode("%EE")` = `�` -- this is because EE has no equivalent character.

But I am trying to decode the string "%ara%" which is invalid, the result I am getting is "%ar%". I don't find the 2nd occurrence of character "a".Can anyone explain me why this is happening??

Comment: The docs also mention it may vary depending on how the string is encoded ie `URLDecode(urlEncodedString[, charset])`. For example, the second value is invalid if treated "utf-8", but produces `î` if decoded with "iso-8859-1".  What charset are you using and what result were you expecting?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in CF. Running `URLDecode("%ara%")` on Lucee /Railo returns as I'd expect.

Comment: @Leigh, thank you for the response. I am not using any charset, I was trying to dump URLDecode("%ara%"). As %ar is invalid hex value, I was expecting � or some other that describes invalid( like "�a%"). But I got a result as "%ar%" with a missing second occurrence of character "a".

Comment: @GeethaKallur - Gotcha.  I am not sure why it is returning "%ar%", but fwiw when I tested it on trycf.com and, it returned that same result for all three engines. John seems to have gotten a different result, so I am curious which versions he was using..